# Google apps script select specific columns to upload into target sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Total beginner here. I am trying to select columns A,B,C from spreadsheet B which has around 40K rows and 25 columns, to spreadsheet A which is a blank document. So, I have two spreadsheets.
This code works fine but I want to select only the columns I need (columns including all the data, not just the headers).

```
function importdata() {  
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID"); //SPREADSHEET TO COPY FROM  
let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("name"); //SHEET (TAB) TO COPY FROM  
sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

let ssThis = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sheetRawData = ssThis.getSheetByName("name"); //SHEET IN THE TARGET SPREADSHEET TO COPY TO
sheetRawData.getRange(1,1,sheetRawData.getLastRow());
}
```

Any idea as to how I can add this into the code above?
Many thanks!

Comment: The provided script does exactly noting, as far as I can tell. But you're saying it works fine. Could you please to describe your workflow: what you have and what you want to get, or/and to provide a working code?

Comment: What do you mean by selecting "specific columns" and "only the columns, not the rows"? Would you like to select only the column headers or the whole content of specific columns (e.g. column A or column F)?

Comment: yes, so I'm working in spreadsheet A, sheet1 where I've imported data from a master sheet (spreadsheet B). Spreadsheet B has about 40K rows and 25 columns, but I'd like to only select a few columns, say columns A,B,C, from spreadsheet B and transfer the columns (with all it's content, not just the headers) to spreadsheet A, sheet1 using the script above .  hope that makes sense

Comment: Do you want to copy the columns (from the sheet B) into the columns with the same names (at the sheet A): A --> A, B --> B, X --> X, etc?

Comment: So Im working with two different spreadsheets here where I want to copy column A,B,C from spreadsheet B to Spreadsheet A. They are separate documents. Spreadsheet A is a blank document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can create an array of selected columns and get / set the values for the ranges corresponding to those columns:

```js
function importSelectedColumns() {  
  
  let selectedColumns = [1, 3, 5];
  
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID"); //SPREADSHEET TO COPY FROM  
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("name"); //SHEET (TAB) TO COPY FROM  
  let ssThis = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheetRawData = ssThis.getSheetByName("name"); //SHEET IN THE TARGET SPREADSHEET TO COPY TO
  
  selectedColumns.forEach(function(column){
    let data = sheet.getRange(1,column, sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
    sheetRawData.getRange(1,column, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).setValues(data);    
  }) 
}
```

Explanation:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is one of several possibilities to loop through several columns subsequently.
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) lets you specify the number and amount of columns to retrieve.
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setvaluesvalues) allows you to import the data from one range into another one.
- Note: The range dimensions of the origin and destination ranges need to match.

**Additional information:**

If you would like to paste your data into an adjacent range starting with column 1, one possible way based on the sample above would be to redefine the loop as following:

```js
  selectedColumns.forEach(function(column,i ){
    let data = sheet.getRange(1,column, sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
    sheetRawData.getRange(1,1+i, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).setValues(data);    
  })
```

Thereby the counter variable `i` is introduced and the notation of the destination column is modified from `column` to `1+i`, meaning that the columns will be set starting with column `1` and increasing by `1` for each loop iteration.

Comment: This one still imports all 25 columns Im afraid.

Comment: In this case I misunderstood what you mean by import. The function above copies the columns 1,3 and 5 from "SHEET (TAB) TO COPY FROM " to "SHEET IN THE TARGET SPREADSHEET TO COPY TO" - is this not what you wanted?

Comment: Hey ziganotschka, perhaps I wasn't clear enough. So Im working with two different spreadsheets (two separate documents), and I want to copy column 1,3,5 from spreadsheet B (sheet A for example) to spreadsheet A (sheet1 for example). Spreadsheet A is a blank document. Thanks! :)

Comment: I believe the code snippet I provided does exactly this. Did you test it?

Comment: probably it makes sense to change `(1,column,sheet.getLastRow(),1)` in the last row by `(1,column,data.length,1)`

Comment: This is in general a good suggestion, though since `let data = sheet.getRange(1,column, sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues()`, in this particular case `sheet.getLastRow()` and `data.length` is the same.

Comment: Hey ziganotschka, thank you, it worked in a new sheet. I have just one more question if you dont mind. When I paste column 4 and 5 for example in sheetRawData, it's pasted in column 4 and 5 (column D and E) see [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Qmp-G_WWdWjCpJjlP028X2FEi33vEUu/view?usp=sharing). So column A, B and C are empty. Is there a way to paste the data starting in column A? Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad it works now! Would you like to paste the columns into adjacent columns in the destination sheet without gaps in-between?

Comment: Hi ziganotscka, yes adjacent columns without space in between. If you look at the photo in my previous comment, there are three empty columns in the target sheet, but is it possible to paste the data in column A?

Comment: I updated my solution to show how to change the destination range notation to accomplish your request!

Comment: Thank you, zig, this is amazing!